# Why is AC sinusoidal?

Tags: electric-current

Why is AC sinusoidal?
Furthermore, as AC voltage oscillates between $+V$ and $-V$, the electrons should move in one direction for a period of time and then move back. Therefore, won't the power transmitted be zero?

Comment: Your argument is equivalent to one saying that rubbing your hands together should generate no heat, since your hands end up in the same place in which they started.

Answer (score 2):

The generators which we use produce sinusoidal ac current.  This arises due to the geometry of the generator. The magnetic flux varies sinusoidally. Therefore, the EMF induced also varies sinusoidally.

However,  note that we also have AC currents with different form factors.  We can have a square wave, triangular wave, etc.

The AC current that powers your home happens to be sinusoidal because the generators we use produce sinusoidally varying currents by default. It is easier to use it as it is produced than convert it to something else.

The net power in an AC cycle is not zero because power is a  function of the square of the current.  Hence,  the power is always positive (except for one special case) irrespective of the direction of the current.

When an AC current transmits zero power,  it is called wattless current. This happens when the current and voltage are exactly 90 degrees out of phase.

Comment: If you've ever put an oscilloscope across the mains (only do this if you know what you are doing and have a suitable probe) you will find that, quite often, mains is not terribly sinusoidal.

Comment: Yes. The waveform will have a countess tiny zig-zag parts because of the presence of harmonics but it is still largly sinusoidal.

Comment: Generally no: while you can obviously model any periodic waveform with a fourier series (so the harmonics are there), what you see is wholesale distortion of the waveform.  The most common thing nowadays seems to be that the peaks of the cycles get clipped off (known as 'flat-topping'), which I think is largely due to switched-mode power-supplies (which tend to take current around the peaks only).